# ToastNotification.Tag not available in background task

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm making a XAML (universal) app for WP8.1 (not silverlight).

I have a background task which I'd like to replace a toast created by the main UI project.  In the main project ToastNotification.Tag is available, but in the background project (windows runtime component) the Tag property doesn't exist on the object.

Is there another way to set the Tag?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is to use reflection:

```
ToastNotification toast = ....;

PropertyInfo nameProperty = toast.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Tag");

nameProperty.SetValue(toast, "ValueOfTag");
```

How servers set the Tag is through a HTTP header therefore clients can't make xml to set the Tag.